# Concentrating multiple <input/> into a string in React

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm returning a bunch of `<input type="text"/>` based on the `props.data` array. When submitting the form, I want to concentrate the value of all the `<input/>` in order, into a single String state. How can I do it?

```
...
<form>
   {props.data.map((ele,ind)=>{
      return <input key={ind} type="text"/>
   })}
   <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a array or object state for the input values. Then, add an `onSubmit` listener on the form and concatenate the strings.

Edit: Instead of using a form, use `window.fetch` or an alternative to send the data. Then you can insert data more easily.

Comment: Let's say my `<input/>` is a component, so I can use `useState` in each of them to get the value. Then how can I send the state value from component(input) to the parents (form), in a correct order, so I can concentrate them to a string?

Comment: Instead of using a form, use `window.fetch` or an alternative to send the data. Then you can insert data more easily.

Comment: I planned to use `fetch` at `onSubmit` to post data to backend later. But first, I need a way to concentrate the state of each `input` component into a string

Comment: if `inputValues` is an array of all the values of the inputs, use `inputValues.join(", ")` to seperate them by a comma.

Comment: The hard part is how can you get the value of the inputs, put them in a correct order array in the parent, and when an input got remove, the value will be remove from the array at the exact position.

Comment: It's not hard. Just use `array.map((v, i) => <input ... />` and use `i` as an index of the state array.